# Grab a row of a pandas dataframe based on value in that row, and a few preceding rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many dataframes with the following structure.

```
    TRCODEP     10101     10201     20101     20201 20203
    43826     4:00:00       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN
    43827         NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN
    43828         NaN  20:00:00       NaN       NaN   NaN
    43829         NaN       NaN       NaN  20:35:00   NaN
    43830    20:45:00       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN
    43829         NaN       NaN  02:00:00       NaN   NaN
```

For each dataframe, I would like to create a new dataframe that selects the row with a non-NaN entry in the `10101` column and the three previous rows. I am having trouble because I might have multiple non-NaN entries for `10101` as you can see above. And, even assuming away that problem I can't seem to slice a dataframe using `df['10101'].notna().index[0]` and `df['10101'].notna().index[0]-3`.

What are my options?

Comment: Your second problem, are you using df.iloc[x:y] where x and y are your bounds?

Comment: @Kyle I was using .loc with the indices. That does work, I was making a basic mistake. I guess my problem reduces to finding all of the indices where df['10101'] is non-NaN, because the `.index` method doesn't work at all.

Comment: What output do you want in this case, given that the first non-null entry is the first row of your sample df?

Comment: @ALollz I would prefer we go to the last instance of 10101 non-NaN if possible. Otherwise, just the row with NaN 0-3 rows preceding it, depending on if those exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that hard. You can do this with `Series.last_valid_index` and some slicing:

```
# get index of last valid non-null value in 10101
idx = df.index.get_loc(df['10101'].last_valid_index())
# slice rows (with some minor bounds checking)
df.iloc[max(0, idx - 3):idx + 1]

   TRCODEP     10101     10201 20101     20201  20203
1    43827       NaN       NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
2    43828       NaN  20:00:00   NaN       NaN    NaN
3    43829       NaN       NaN   NaN  20:35:00    NaN
4    43830  20:45:00       NaN   NaN       NaN    NaN
```